# Hibernate/JPA unable to find type of subclass in Single Table inheritance strategy

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Java 11, Spring Boot, MySQL, Liquibase, JPA and Hibernate here. I have the following entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String refId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "field_descriptors")
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "field_descriptor_id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column = @Column(name = "field_descriptor_ref_id"))
})
@Data
public class FieldDescriptorEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "field_descriptor_pattern")
    private String pattern;

    @Column(name = "field_descriptor_label")
    private String label;

    @Column(name = "field_descriptor_is_required")
    private Boolean required;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "data_flow_steps")
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "data_flow_step_id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column = @Column(name = "data_flow_step_ref_id"))
})
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "data_flow_step_type_label", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Data
public class DataFlowStepEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "data_flow_step_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "data_flow_step_description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "data_flow_step_ordinal")
    private Integer ordinal;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ADD_COLUMN")
@Data
public class AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity extends DataFlowStepEntity {

    @Column(name = "data_flow_step_field_id")
    private FieldDescriptorEntity fieldDescriptor;

}
```

And the following SQL used to create the `field_descriptors` and `data_flow_steps` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS field_descriptors (
    field_descriptor_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    field_descriptor_ref_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID()),
    field_descriptor_pattern VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    field_descriptor_label VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    field_descriptor_is_required TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_field_descriptors PRIMARY KEY (field_descriptor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_flow_steps (
    -- base fields used by all step types
    data_flow_step_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data_flow_step_ref_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID()),
    data_flow_step_type_label VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    data_flow_step_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    data_flow_step_description VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    data_flow_step_ordinal BIGINT NOT NULL,

    -- these are the subclass fields that get reused across different types of steps
    data_flow_step_field_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,

    CONSTRAINT data_flow_steps PRIMARY KEY (data_flow_step_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_data_flow_steps_step_field_id FOREIGN KEY (data_flow_step_field_id) REFERENCES field_descriptors (field_descriptor_id)
);
```

I have JPA/Hibernate set to validate schema at startup. When the app starts up and runs the migrations, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine
type for: myapp.entities.FieldDescriptorEntity, at table:
data_flow_steps, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(data_flow_step_field_id)]
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Column` annotation is designed for specify the mapped column for a field.

#### Problem

Here you using it wrong:

```java
@Column(name = "data_flow_step_field_id")
private FieldDescriptorEntity fieldDescriptor;
```

In this case the related **field** even if that is a foreing key **is a relation** not a single column. Just imagine, how should Hibernate initialize the related `FieldDescriptorEntity` if it is just a single column.

#### Solution

Tell Hibernate that field is a kind of relationship to an other entity.

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "field_descriptor_id")
private FieldDescriptorEntity fieldDescriptor;
```

**NOTE #1**: In this case the `@JoinColumn` annotation is optional. @ManyToOne association assumes that `AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity` primary id field is used to join with `FieldDescriptorEntity`'s referenced foreign key column.

**NOTE #2**: Default fetch mode of `@ManyToOne` is `EAGER`. I prefer to use `LAZY` fetch mode.

Here is two test cases to show how to fetch this assosciation eager.

```java
class PersistTest {
    private static final Supplier<EntityManagerFactory> emf = () -> Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");

    @BeforeAll
    static void fill() {
        doInJPA(emf, em -> {
            var descEnt = new FieldDescriptorEntity();
            descEnt.setLabel("foo");
            ;
            em.persist(descEnt);

            var accCol = new AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity();
            accCol.setDescription("bazinga");
            accCol.setFieldDescriptor(descEnt);
            em.persist(accCol);
        });
    }

    //language=hql
    final String lazyQuery = """
            select o from AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity o
                where o.description = :desc
            """;

    @Test
    void lazyCheck() {
        doInJPA(emf, em -> {
            var stepEntity = em.createQuery(lazyQuery, AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity.class)
                    .setParameter("desc", "bazinga")
                    .getSingleResult();
            var descriptor = stepEntity.getFieldDescriptor();
            assertNotNull(descriptor);
            assertEquals("foo", descriptor.getLabel());

        });
    }

    //language=hql
    final String eagerQuery = """
            select o from AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity o 
                join fetch o.fieldDescriptor d
                where o.description = :desc
            """;

    @Test
    void eagerCheck() {
        doInJPA(emf, em -> {
            var stepEntity = em.createQuery(eagerQuery, AddColumnDataFlowStepEntity.class)
                    .setParameter("desc", "bazinga")
                    .getSingleResult();
            var descriptor = stepEntity.getFieldDescriptor();
            assertNotNull(descriptor);
            assertEquals("foo", descriptor.getLabel());

        });
    }
}
```

Finally, I strognly recommend to avoid using Lombok `@Data` annotation with JPA entities. It may cause a lot of problems and pitfalls.